# docker container port closes after first connection

Tags: docker, port, netcat

If I start a docker container like this

```
docker container run -it -p 9001:9001 alpine nc -p 9001 -l -k
```

I can then send this little dockerized netcat server some plain text from a terminal on the host using

```
nc localhost 9001
```

But, once I `^C` the netcat in my host terminal, I can't make a new connection to the docker container. Redoing the command tells me the connection succeeds, but netcat closes right away

```
$ nc localhost 9001 -v
Connection to localhost 9001 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Since I'm running my container in interactive mode, I can see that the netcat inside the container is still running.

So why can't I reconnect? Or at least, what can I do to resolve the issue?

It works just fine if I do it all without docker.

Comment: I think this is because of the netcat version included in Busybox.

Comment: @EstebanGarcia, you're right! make it an answer for the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the netcat version included in Busybox.

Comment: yup. the `-k` option doesn't exist for the version in the container. that option is what allows reconnects